# Turn off retweet in embedded timeline

Tags: twitter

I am using embedded timeline in my drupal site to pull twitter tweets using the widget id. It is working fine. But i want to turn off the retweets. How can i achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way around this but it's not perfect, you can filter by #. So if you have a brand name or keyword you regularly use you you can filter by this, most re-tweets won't show. Search for #YOURHASHTAG from:yourhandle

I use this on my site as I wanted 3 different twitter timelines on different pages showing tweets by me filtered by #adobe #autodesk and #techcomms on the relevant pages.